# Play Framework + Scala + Couchbase?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, couchbase

I would like to use Couchbase in a Play Framework + Scala project. I have seen Scala based Play Modules like, https://github.com/leon/play-salat, to hook up Play and MongoDB. Just wondering if anyone has done anything similar for Couchbase or if anyone has used Couchbase with Play before?

Comment: See Couchbase plugin here (Play Framework 2.1) : https://github.com/mathieuancelin/play2-couchbase

Answer (score 4):

A recent article by [Michael Nitschinger](https://twitter.com/daschl) might be of some use to you. He implemented the couchbase solution using java, but implementation in scala should be pretty straight forward. You can find [the article here](http://www.scoop.it/t/playframework/p/2189138216/a-real-time-chat-with-play-java-and-couchbase-part-1).

Comment: Thanks a million for the links, really helpful and just want I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I have used Play framework + Scala + Couchbase and it works like a charm!
I can certainly recommend you to use it.
There are modules that you can use to make it real easy to use:
http://reactivecouchbase.org/

It includes a very good tutorial and samples.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not listed on [the modules page](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Modules), it probably doesn't exist (or isn't used on large-scale).

You can always check/use/transform/tweak the Java version(s) of existing framework and create a module for the community! ;)

Comment: Thanks I might just do that...